# access windows file system problem

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs

i'm using ubuntu 12.10 and its a dual boot.till yesterday i'v access windows through ubuntu.but today when i try to access windows through ubuntu it shows error message. here it is,

> Blockquote
>   Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/dingo/A2B20C30B20C0B8B: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/dingo/A2B20C30B20C0B8B"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
>   The NTFS partition is hibernated. Please resume and shutdown Windows
>   properly, or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option, or
>   mount the volume read-write with the 'remove_hiberfile' mount option.
>   For example type on the command line:
>   mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /media/dingo/A2B20C30B20C0B8B

(for long time i'm not logged to windows.).give me some help. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to log on into your windows, then shut it down. Maybe your windows was hibernated without your notice

Comment: hi caisar, yes that is shown in the error message.i did that earlier. but it doesn't work .therefore i wrote to this.is there any way to solve this?? thanks

Comment: Maybe this link help: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: hi caisar ,thanks for the link.i'll go through that.